# Where ElasticSearch Store Original Document Before Executing Flush Command?

Tags: elasticsearch

Based on this, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/near-real-time.html, when we index a document, first document is appended in memory buffer and transaction log.

When refresh happen, it will copy document in memory buffer into segments-in-memory and memory buffer will be emptied. Once elasticsearch execute flush operation, then segments-in-memory will persist in disk and also original doc. And transaction log will be emptied as well.

Correct me if I am wrong, segment doesn't store original document, it is only contain inverted index, then where ES stores original document before flushing happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elastic built on Apache Lucene , Lucene's index falls into the family of indexes known as an inverted index. This is because it can list, for a term, the documents that contain it. This is the inverse of the natural relationship, in which documents list terms. The index stores statistics about terms in order to make term-based search more efficient with aid of tokenizer and analyzer patterns.

When you adding or ingesting new documents you are creating new segments. Every changes are buffered in memory and periodically flushed , Note that flushing just moves the internal buffered state in IndexWriter into the index, but these changes are not visible to IndexReader and the operation log and buffer will be cleared.

You can find out more about segments and Apache Lucene pre-indexing procedure in [Here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/fileformats.html).